# Could there have been an alternative decision made for Werner?

Tags: better-call-saul

I understand why Werner Ziegler couldn't have been trusted given his actions, but what parts demonstrated that letting him live would have 100% led to trouble for Gus's operation?

Could Ziegler reasonably have gone back home or back to the lab without harm or foul?

Comment: Why does it need to 100% lead to trouble to get him killed? Gus personally murdered someone who’d worked for him much longer with a box-cutter just because he’d been seen looking around a murder scene (maybe a little bit to scare Walt and Jesse too). Gus is perfectly fine murdering people if it reduces his risk of being discovered.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But in the case of Werner Ziegler, the final decision rested with Mike, who, while callous AF, is not really portrayed as someone in favor of avoidable killing....

Comment: @rackandboneman I don’t think it did. If Mike didn’t kill Werner, Gus would have, and without Werner just about managing to divert his wife, probably her too. Assuming Lalo didn’t catch up with them and wreak some havoc first.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite there would have been plenty of opportunities to make Werner dead as far as Gus was concerned....